# My Command prompt & Anaconda prompt is crashing

Tags: anaconda, command

My Command prompt & Anaconda prompt is crashing while opening
Also tried via VS code, error pop ups and says
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.